# Python Selenium: WebDriverWait, element not found despite loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, selenium, wait

I'm trying to load a URL which has dynamic HTML. The selenium webdriver loads the URL fine, but it appears to be searching for elements before the HTML has fully rendered. I tried WebDriverWait, but that does not appear to work.

Interestingly, after selenium fails to find the element, I can manually use the Chrome developer tools to find the element successfully.

Any ideas?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

chromepath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe"
url        = "https://www.msci.com/end-of-day-data-search"
delay      = 15 #seconds

br = webdriver.Chrome(chromepath)
br.get(url)

try:
    br.find_element_by_class_name("accept-btn").click()
    print("accepted terms and conditions")
finally:
    try:
        labelxpath   = "//*[@id='form-content']/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/span"
        labelElement = WebDriverWait(br, delay).until(lambda br: br.find_element_by_xpath(labelxpath))
        print(labelElement)
    except:
        print("could not find label")
        br.close()
```

Script results: 
"accepted terms and conditions"
"could not find label"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's not only about waiting for the page to load.

The element you are looking for is inside an iframe. You need to *switch to it's context* before searching for the element:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(0)  # 0 here is an index - using 0 since there is only one iframe
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed everything